# Ubuntu Graphics Driver / Screen Resoloution Problem

Tags: drivers, graphics, resolution

I have an old laptop that I installed Ubuntu on from Windows XP previously.  After the installation I noticed the screen resolution is wrong and not all of the screen fits on the display.

After researching this, I have ran:
      lshw -c video

and obtained the following output:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED     
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter
   vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 10
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d4000000-d401ffff ioport:9000(size=128)
```

I am a complete newbie to Linux/Ubuntu and not sure what to do to fix my display.  After I fix the ability to see things correctly, I hope I can learn the system more easily.  As such, any help would be gratefully received to help me get past the first hurdle.

Crudly, I think the problem is simply that I do not have the correct graphics driver for the system and need to upgrade/install one.  Problem: which one and how?

I never had this problem when the laptop ran Windows XP.

Thanks

Comment: You have the above info, google '+Ubuntu +SIS +771 +driver' for starters.

Comment: Thanks- I did this which helped a lot and discovered the SiS 771/671 product is quite a common problem users have with Ubuntu 14.04.  I went to Xdiagnose and ticked all 3 debug as per advice [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449820/ubuntu-14-04-screen-resolution-too-low) which allowed me to change the resolution in the Display Size settings 10 1028 x 768.   This helped a lot as now I can at least see the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

First maybe try to "Detect Display" in GUI in top right corner icon 
go to:

Goto Ubuntu Menu: System -> Preference -> Display

If this autodetection does not work I suggest you to read Wiki page
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Dynamically_testing_different_resolutions

Here you see xrandr command and some examples like:

xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768 --rate 60

BTW You should also mention which Ubuntu you are using as from version 13 they got new
GUI.