# Cannot get resolution of 1280x800 on my "SiS M760GX" video card

Tags: xorg, display-resolution, sis-graphics

[This is a near-perfect solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/504632/327339) for me to get a better resolution than 640x480, but is still not quite right!

I have a an Acer Aspire 5000 with "SiS M760GX" video card (`lspci -v` returns `Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 661/741/760 PCI/AGP or 662/761Gx PCIE VGA Display Adapter (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])`) and using this **xorg.conf** file shown below I can now get resolutions of **1280x768, 1024x768, 800x600, or 640x480**, instead of just 640x480, which was waaaaay too low of a resolution. However, my screen's native resolution is **1280x800**, so it still looks a little off. **ANY IDEA HOW I CAN GET 1280X800 TO WORK?**

Note that I'm running Xubuntu 16.04.3 64-bit. The Acer Aspire 5000 is from approximately 2005.

Here's my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file (Originally posted here by javier-ejsf [post #10]! - https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2215422):

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Generic Video Card"
    VendorName  "Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]"
        BoardName   "771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter"
    Busid "PCI:1:0:0"
    Driver "vesa"
    Screen 0
        Option "UseFBDev" "true"
        Option "DPMS"
        Option "ShadowFB"
        Option "MaxXFBMem"
        VideoRam 262016
        Option "RenderAccel" "true"
        Option "AllowGLXWithComposite" "true"
        Option "backingstore" "true"
        Option "AddARGBGLXVisuals" "True"

EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier    "Configured Monitor"
    Vendorname    "Generic LCD Display"
    Modelname    "LCD Panel 1280x800"
    HorizSync 20-107
        VertRefresh 50-185
  modeline  "800x600@56" 36.0 800 824 896 1024 600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync
  modeline  "800x600@60" 40.0 800 840 968 1056 600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync
  modeline  "1280x768@60" 80.14 1280 1344 1480 1680 768 769 772 795 -hsync +vsync
  modeline  "1280x720@60" 74.48 1280 1336 1472 1664 720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync
  modeline  "1280x800@60" 83.46 1280 1344 1480 1680 800 801 804 828 -hsync +vsync
    Gamma    1.0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier    "Default Screen"
    Monitor        "Configured Monitor"
    Device        "Configured Video Device"
    Defaultdepth    24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth    24
        Virtual    1280    768
        Modes        "1280x768@60"    "1280x720@60"    "800x600@60"    "1280x800@60"    "800x600@56"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load "dri"
    Load "dbe" # Double-Buffering Extension
    Load "v4l" # Video for Linux
    Load "extmod"
    Load "type1"
    Load "freetype"
    Load "glx" # 3D layer
    Load "GLcore"
    Load "i2c"
    Load "bitmap"
    Load "ddc"
    Load "int10"
    Load "vbe"
    Load "speedo"
    Load "record"
EndSection

Section "DRI"
        Mode 0666
EndSection
```

What' I've already tried:
If I try changing "Virtual 1280 768" to "Virtual 1280 800" all it does is make my screen vertically extend beyond the edges of the monitor, so by moving the mouse to the top or the bottom it will pan the screen up or down to see the extra 32 pixels. This is NOT what I want.

Comment: SIS chipsets are a pain in linux. It used to be an xserver-xorg-video-sis package that let you get full resolution. Are you using a default driver or have you installed an alternative?

Comment: default driver. The xorg.conf file above is telling the system to use the "vesa" driver that comes with Ubuntu/Xubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the 1280x800 resolution on modern Ubuntu versions.

It was possible on Ubuntu 12.04. Now the X.org doesn't support the SiS obsolete modesetting method.

You can use only VESA modes.

Comment: Where can I see a list of available VESA modes to choose from?

Comment: I see 1280x1024 here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions) for instance, but I don't even see 1280x768 anywhere in that list, so how is it that I'm getting that resolution then?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_display_standard It is SXGA standard. It is a de facto standard.

Comment: Anyway there is nothing you can do but install 12.04.

Comment: I think you are mistaken. 1280x768 doesn't show up anywhere in the link you posted. Nevertheless, I will accept that 1280x768 is the best I can do, and I'll stick with it, running in Xubuntu 16.04.3 64-bit. I for sure don't want to downgrade, especially considering how close my current 1280x768 is to my desired 1280x800--it's only off by 4% in the y-axis.